# Script expression to get part of a string?

Tags: centos, bash, scripting

I'm using the bash shell in CentOS, version ...

```
$ uname -a
Linux mydomain.com 3.2.29-48.63.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Sep 15 01:43:12 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

In my shell script, I want to get part of a string, specifically, everything before the last dash ("-").  So if my string is "my-importer-1.0.ear," I want to extract "my-importer".  However, the expression below

```
prefix=${fname%-*}
```

is only returning "my", because its matching against the first dash.  How can I adjust the expression to match everything up until the last dash?

Comment: Use sed instead?  `echo my-importer-1.0.ear | sed -re 's/^(.*)-.*$/\1/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're not using `%%` which deletes the longest match from the end of the string and thus gives you `my` whereas a `%` deletes the shortest match and provides (for you example) what you want

```
fname=my-importer-1.0.ear
echo ${fname%%-*}
my
```

whereas

```
echo ${fname%-*}
my-importer
```